# Can't figure out regular expressions in C++

Tags: c++, regex, mingw

I'm new to regular expressions and can't really get my head around it.

I'm just trying to match any letter:

```
int main() {
    regex("[a-z]")
    return 1;
}
```

when I run it I get a compile time error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

However, the even simpler example, works fine:

```
int main() {
    regex("a")
    return 1;
}
```

I'm sure there is some basic syntax I'm missing, I've tried adding the regex::ECMAScript flag but no effect.

Note that I'm not trying to use the regex object, in fact I'm not even storing it. I'm just attempting to create it using the constructor as in the examples given here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex/

The compiler is GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match

Comment: whats with the downvotes without an explanation?

anyway, matching is a latter issue, i just want to creata an object that what a pattern.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex/

Comment: What compiler? What version?

Comment: @JamesKanze gcc 4.8.1

Comment: From what I can tell, regular expressions don't work in g++ 4.8.2 (the version I have); I doubt that they worked in earlier versions either.  (Your code works fine with VS 2013.)

Comment: thanks, i got it running using the flag std::regex_constants::basic, but so far not matching, that however might be my fault

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved specifying the flag:

```
regex("pattern", std::regex_constants::basic)
```